# Will new Skyrim SE saves work on the original Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I know this is the oppposite of what everyone wants to know, but is it possible to use the saves from Skyrim SE on the original Skyrim?

I would like to start a new save in Skyrim SE on my main computer, but I have another computer I use from time to time that's not powerful enough to run the new one. 
So if I use unmodded saves on both, can I also use the other computer with the original Skyrim with the Skryim SE save and continue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This post](https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/5bf6at/transfer_saves_from_special_edition_to_old_skyrim/?) is by someone who attempted to carry out the reverse transfer that you described. This is the error message that they received:

> Unlike 99% of you lot, I started my Skyrim adventure on remastered version of the game. Now I'd like to mod the original skyrim and continue my game on the modded skyrim.
>
> After copying my save files to skyrim folder, i get 'This save game was created on later version. Please update your game'.

Thus, it looks like you cannot transfer a Skyrim SE save to the original Skyrim.

Comment: That looks like a post from some random guy on the steam forums. Not a lot of credibility, as far as evidence goes.

Comment: If they truly changed no game scripting/data, that doesn't add up. The architecture of the save files is determined by the game data files, so either the game is unchanged and saves are compatible or they're incompatible and they did change more than the render engine. I imagine more research is in our future! ;)

Comment: Hm. I wonder if it's merely a version check (i.e., a bit flipping tool would make it work), or if there is a real data incompatibility. If the latter, that would indicate something else has changed… Anyway, +1 for the SCIENCE citation.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie possibly. I just remembered that Skyrim SE is free for people who have the original Skyrim + all DLC, so I can verify this one way or another when I go home today.

Comment: I actually got around to test this myself, and the answer is correct. You are prompted that the save is intended for a newer version.